# excel date showing different formats in different machines

Tags: coldfusion, lucee

I am using spreadsheetformatcellvalue to enter the date in the excel like this

```
<cfset spreadsheetSetCellValue(objxls, "#datecreated#", 2,1,"Date")>
```

it works, but i noticed something, i have two machines and in one machine date is displaying as: `02-19-2021`

and in other excel it is showing `19/02/2021`

what i noticed is that it seems to be using the locale specified of the windows. how can i force to use the format of `dd/mm/yyyy` across all machines irrespective of locale

can i use something in ColdFusion to make it work..

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what the users should be able to do with the data once it's in Excel.  If they need to perform any date functions, don't do anything.  If they simply have to look at it, then Adrian's answer will work.

Comment: `..how can i force to use the format of dd/mm/yyyy...` I think you answered your own question: ie. [apply a format](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetformatcell.html).  It doesn't look like the code is doing that, so you end up with the default, which varies by machine and locale.

Comment: What version of ColdFusion, JDK and OS are you using?

Comment: i am coldfusion 2016, windows and jdk i donno

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just format the date.

```
<cfset spreadsheetSetCellValue(objxls, "#dateFormat(datecreated, 'dd/mm/yyyy')#", 2,1,"Date")>
```

Comment: ok, i tried it but the issue is still if opens in another computer, it shows the date in the mm-dd-yyyy format

Comment: Prepend a single quote to the formatted date.

Comment: Formatting won't work when using datatype "date", as CF just parses the value back into a date object before populating the cell.  As far as the display, sounds like CF is using one of the [locale specific date formats](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/4d8a65ab-8eff-46b8-8de8-9bde34e18a11.jpg) as a default for "date" cells.  Applying [SpreadSheetSetCellFormat(...)](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetformatcell.html) with the correct date format should work

Comment: Well, learn something new every day...  For some reason that *does* seem to work. Absolutely no idea why though. Will have to dig into Adobe's black magic more and see if it works with different locale settings too ;-)